# Gradle - Cannot import viewpagerindicator in Android Studio using gradle dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, android-gradle-plugin

So I am trying to use actionbarsherlock and viewpagerindicator and for some reason, the viewpagerindicator library does not get imported for some reason. Anyone have any idea?

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

**This import errors out "Cannot resolve symbol viewpageindicator**

```
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;
```

**These is my "Messages gradle tasks"**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\myAppName\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\myAppName\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\myAppName\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\myAppName\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\myAppName\app\build\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.myAppName.app --output-text-symbols C:\myAppName\app\build\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    C:\myAppName\app\build\res\all\debug\values\values.xml:911: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle'.
    C:\myAppName\app\build\res\all\debug\values\values.xml:914: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.TabPageIndicator'.
    C:\myAppName\app\build\res\all\debug\values\values.xml:934: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fadeDelay'.
    C:\myAppName\app\build\res\all\debug\values\values.xml:933: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fadeLength'.
    C:\myAppName\app\build\res\all\debug\values\values.xml:931: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectedColor'.


C:\myAppName\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
    No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle'.
    Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.TabPageIndicator'.
    No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fadeDelay'.
    No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fadeLength'.
    No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectedColor'.
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio? What do you mean by "does not get imported"?

Comment: @ScottBarta, I just updated my question with the exact errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't import ViewPagerIndicator via

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.0'
```

because that Maven artifact is just a jar of the Java library, but VPI relies on Android resources that aren't in the jar.

Maven artifacts that have AAR packaging do have resources and will work, but VPI isn't packaged that way. It has apklib packaging, but the Android Gradle plugin doesn't support that.

You'll need to download the source and set it up as an android-library module.

You weren't specific about what version of Android Studio you're running, but I'm willing to bet that your problem with the import not working is due to the fact that you're running something earlier than 0.4.3; bugs have been fixed in that area since then.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was not aware of that. Would updating to  newer than 0.4.3 version help me import the library or would I still have to import it as a java library?

Comment: No, you'll still have to set up VPI as an android-library module in Gradle. 0.4.3 just fixes bugs where newly-added dependencies still don't show up right for imports and syntax highlighting even though the project builds okay.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adding the library not through dependencies but through adding it to the library folder.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that works. It won't help you with the resources it needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can import AAR using [this instruction](http://blog.haunted-soft.com/2013/10/viewpagerindicator-aar-packaged.html):

In your build.gradle include http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven as repository **priorior** to mavenCentral:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Use in your dependencies as usual:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
}
```

Comment: i try doing this inside another subproject i have in android studio but i get an error Widget.TabIndicator etc style not found. any idea what i might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @serge's answer if you have `repositories` defined in `allprojects` tag you'll need to add it there too.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

It's work for me.

And make sure to re sync gradle and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

My root build.gradle is:

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

and the dependency is:  compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

Its works like bomb :-)

Comment: i have tried this.... it dosen't give any error but i am unable to import any classes. What is wrong?